# Shade Bounded Region along y-axis

Tags: maple

I plotted a line but want to shade the area between 2 and 4 along the y axis to illustrate area under the curve but cannot figure out how to do that, can anyone help? This is the code, which is rather simple

```
>y:=(2*x);

>plot(y,x=0..3);
```

[image: Unshaded plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it difficult to understand just what region you have in mind.

Is it this?

```
restart;

y := 2*x:

plots:-display(
  plot(2*x, x=0..3),
  plots:-inequal([Y>=y, Y>=2, Y<=4], x=0..3, Y=0..6,
                 'nolines', 'color'="Burgundy")
);
```

[image]

Of course you could omit the curve (line) `y=2*x by` removing the call to `plot` above.

If you have some other region in mind then you should be able to adjust the call to `plots:-inequal` accordingly.

There are other ways to accomplish such things, such as calling `plot` with its `filled` option. You can also use `plottools:-reflect`, or use the parametric calling sequence of `plot`, to flip `x` and `y` axes.

I figure that you might be wanting to avoid having to "solve for x", to get `x` values corresponding to `y=2` and `y=4` (even though in this example of `y=2*x` you can do that in your head).

These are reasons why I think you'd likley find it easiest to just use `plots:-inequal`.

[edit: for followup comment about 8 rectangles]

First, a slightly different example, hopefully for more clarity.

```
restart;

x:=arcsin(y/6):

P := plots:-display(
  plot(x, y=2..5),
  plots:-inequal([X<=x], y=2..5, X=0..1.2,
                 'nolines', 'color'=pink)
):

plots:-display(
  plot(2, color=black, linestyle=dot),
  plot(5, color=black, linestyle=dot),
  plot([x, y, y=0..6]),
  plottools:-transform((x,y)->[y,x])(P),
  view=[0..1.2,0..6],
  labels=["x","y"],
  size=[500,300]
);
```

[image]

The upper of lower sums (using rectangles) can be visualized using the `RiemannSum` command from the `Student:-Calculus1` package. (Or you could use the `seq` command and construct them all by formulas for their corners -- but that just seems like a lot of awkward bookkeeping.)

You can of course remove any of the parts passed below to the `plots:-display` command.

```
restart;

with(Student:-Calculus1):

x:=arcsin(y/6):

P:=RiemannSum(x, y=2..5, method = upper, output = plot,
              partition=8,
              boxoptions=[filled=[color=pink,transparency=.5]],
              caption=""):

rP:=plottools:-transform((x,y)->[y,x])(P):

plots:-display(
  plot(2, color=black, linestyle=dot),
  plot(5, color=black, linestyle=dot),
  plot([x, y, y=0..6]),
  rP,
  view=[0..1.2,0..6],
  labels=["x","y"],
  size=[500,300]
);
```

[image]
Or,

```
restart;

with(Student:-Calculus1):

x:=arcsin(y/6):

P:=RiemannSum(x, y=2..5, method = lower, output = plot,
              partition=8,
              boxoptions=[filled=[color=pink,transparency=.5]],
              caption=""):

rP:=plottools:-transform((x,y)->[y,x])(P):

plots:-display(
  plot(2, color=black, linestyle=dot),
  plot(5, color=black, linestyle=dot),
  plot([x, y, y=0..6]),
  rP,
  view=[0..1.2,0..6],
  labels=["x","y"],
  size=[500,300]
);
```

[image]

All these examples would be a little less complicated if you wanted the area between the curve and the x-axis instead.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! I am exporting as eps to include in a maple document. Thank you for the detailed explanation as well so that I can learn and possibly help someone else in the future.

Comment: Could you tell me how I would show a certain number of rectangles in that same region? Lets say, 8 rectangles between 2 and 4?

Comment: Please see the edited update to my answer, for 8 rectangles. You also add the `plots:-inequal` solid shaded region in there as well (and adjust colors as desired).

Comment: You have gone above and beyond, I wish I could give more than one upvote. Thank you a ton for this little learning session!